# mongoengine - index on a key inside of an embedded document?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

MongoDB allows for an index on a key inside of an embedded document:

```
db.things.ensureIndex({"address.city": 1})
```

Is there a way to do this using mongoengine?

Comment: did you try it? there is an ensure_index function in mongoengine

Comment: @DrDee I'm trying to enforce this in the schema. I can do that with any field using the argument unique=True, but what about a key inside an embedded field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a field on an embedded document with `unique=True`:

```
>>> class Nested(EmbeddedDocument):
...     a = StringField(unique=True)
...     b = StringField()
... 
>>> class Outer(Document):
...     inner = EmbeddedDocumentField(Nested)
...     c = StringField()
... 
>>> o = Outer()
>>> o.c = 'abc'
>>> o.inner = Nested(a='a', b='b')
>>> o.save()
>>> o2 = Outer()
>>> o2.c = 'abc'
>>> o2.inner = Nested(a='a', b='B')
>>> o2.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mongoengine/document.py", line 176, in save
    raise OperationError(message % unicode(err))
mongoengine.queryset.OperationError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: test.outer.$inner.a_1  dup key: { : "a" })
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class Nested(EmbeddedDocument):
    a = StringField(unique=True)
    b = StringField()

class Outer(Document):
    inner = EmbeddedDocumentField(Nested)
    c = StringField()
    meta = {"indexes": ['inner.a']}
```

That's all.